# Is my route53 cluster domain set up properly?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I got this output with dig

```
 dig NS markovic.mydomain.com.

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.7-Ubuntu <<>> NS markovic.mydomain.com.
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 61780
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;markovic.mydomain.com.     IN  NS

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Mon May 13 10:10:05 CEST 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 50
```

And

```
host -t NS markovic.mydomain.com.
Host markovic.mydomain.com. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Hosted zones image
[image]

I am newbee to AWS,how could I decipher if I have set the domain in a right way?

Comment: I was trying to answer this question, but it needs some clarifications in my opinoin: Please specify whether you have registered your DNS name through Route 53 or if it is just a zone which you have created there,

 and what is your desired output: Have you created a zone which you want to be able to resolve through recursive queries ie through root server delegation or is it something to use for internal use only.

Comment: how to check if I have registered DNS through Route 53?

Comment: I will edit with picture.

Comment: I want to create a high-availability Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `markovic.mydomain.com` is the actual domain name and it is known to your nameservers:

```
$ dig soa markovic.mydomain.com. @ns-520.awsdns-01.net.
...    
;; ANSWER SECTION:
markovic.mydomain.com.  900 IN  SOA ns-1458.awsdns-54.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
markovic.mydomain.com.  172800  IN  NS  ns-1458.awsdns-54.org.
markovic.mydomain.com.  172800  IN  NS  ns-1742.awsdns-25.co.uk.
markovic.mydomain.com.  172800  IN  NS  ns-351.awsdns-43.com.
markovic.mydomain.com.  172800  IN  NS  ns-520.awsdns-01.net.
```

However `mydomain.com` nameservers don't know about `markovic.mydomain.com`:

```
$ host -t ns markovic.mydomain.com. ns1.mydomain.com.
Using domain server:
Name: ns1.mydomain.com.
Address: 66.96.142.148#53

Host markovic.mydomain.com. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

**Background:** DNS works as a chain.

1. In your case the *Root nameservers* (e.g. `a.root-servers.net.`) must know what are the nameservers for `com` domain (e.g. `a.gtld-servers.net.`).
2. The `com` nameservers must know what are the nameservers for `mydomain.com` domain. They are `ns1.mydomain.com.` to `ns4.mydomain.com.`
3. Finally the `mydomain.com` nameservers must know what are the nameservers for `markovic.mydomain.com` - and here the chain breaks, the `mydomain.com` nameservers have no clue.

You can't just *make up a domain name* and hope it will work. Your domain **always** has to be registered with the higher level nameservers. Otherwise no one on the internet will find your nameservers and in turn your website, etc.

You've got a couple of options:

1. **Register your own domain** directly under `.com` or `.org` or `.net` etc. They start from some $12/year. It will be yours for as long as you pay the annual fee. For instance you can register `supercool-markovic.com` through AWS Route53 domain registration and then create a hosted zone for it also in Route53.
2. **Get free subdomain**. I doubt `mydomain.com` permits custom subdomains, not sure, but there are services like [freedns.afraid.org](http://freedns.afraid.org/) where you can create a subdomain of one of their domains and point it to the AWS nameservers.

Either way you can't just make up a domain, you have to properly *register it* in the upstream nameservers.

Hope that helps :)